# NameError: name 'worksheet' is not defined when trying to access Google sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to fetch all values from a Google spreadsheet using gspread module.

I get an error

```
NameError: name 'worksheet' is not defined
```

Given below is what I am trying to do:

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials) .    <<- Pass in Google sheet API to establish connection
list_of_lists = worksheet.get_all_values()
```

Could anyone assist. Thanks..

Comment: The error says that you have tried to use a variable `worksheet` that you haven't created.  Clearly, you haven't created this variable in the two lines of code above, but are these two lines all of your code?  If not, please edit your question to include all of your code.

Comment: @LukeWoodward, I am basically trying to connect to Google drive API and then try to view the contents in the google sheet. Only thing that I have not included is the credentials. Wondering how to pass in the worksheet argument..

Comment: I assume you mean Google Sheets API rather than Google Drive API, right?  There are code examples on how to open a spreadsheet at https://github.com/burnash/gspread .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the **gspread library**. From the documentation which is the same flow as the google API, there are steps you have to follow:
1. **Authorize the client**
`client = pygsheets.authorize()`
2. **Select the file you want to open**. gspread has three options:
  2.a open using filename:
    `sh = gc.open('Your File name')`
  2.b open using sheet id(which you can get from the url after this part *https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*:
    `sht = gc.open_by_key('0BmgG6nO_6dprdS1MN3d3MkdPa142WFRrdnRRUWl1UFE')`
  2.c open using the entire url:
     `sht = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Bm...FE&hl')`
3. **Select the sheet or tab**.
Once its open, you can select the sheet or tab you want to get the data from
  3.a Select worksheet by index. Worksheet indexes start from zero:
    `worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)`
  3.b by title:
    `worksheet = sh.worksheet("January")`
  3.c Or the most common case: Sheet1, assuming the sheet name doesn't have spaces:
    `worksheet = sh.sheet1`
*Note:

To get a list of all worksheets:*

`worksheet_list = sh.worksheets()`
4. **Extract data**. Lastly to get all values of the sheet:
`list_of_lists = worksheet.get_all_values()`
So to summarize:
1. Authorize client
2. Select Spreadsheet
3. Select Sheet or Tab
4. Pull data

Link to the docs:
https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/